# Android SQLiteDatabase delete function

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have one strange situation with SQLiteDatabase.delete function

This is don't delete any null records:

```
SQLiteDatabase.delete(Table, "ifnull(Field, 0) = ?", new String[]{"0"});
```

This delete all null records without any problems:

```
SQLiteDatabase.execSQL("delete from Table where ifnull(Field, 0) = 0");
```

Can somebody explain me, why in first case null records not deleted?

Answer (score 1):

`0` is a number, `"0"` is a string. Values of different types are not equal.

The Android database API does not allow you to use any type other than `String` for parameters to `delete()`. If you want to put a number into an SQL statement, do not use a parameter but insert it directly.